# Proofs wether a limit exists or not.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

Let me define a function:-

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 2x & \text{, } x≠5 \\ x & \text{, } x=5 \end{cases}$$

Now let me find:-

$$\lim_{x \to\ 5} f(x) = 10$$

Now I will try to prove that this limit exists.

According to the formal definition of limits:-

$$ 0<|x-c|< \delta \implies 0<|f(x)-L|< \epsilon$$

I would not mention here the other requirements and conditions because I think people here know the formal definition of limits.

So that would mean we should be able to express $\delta$ in terms of $\epsilon$.

Let me try to do this:-

Using the definition:-

$$0<|x-5|<\delta$$

To express it in the form of $\epsilon$. We will try to get the above inequality in the form of $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon$. :-

$$0<2×|x-5|< 2× \delta$$

Which is the same as :-

$$0<|2x-10| < 2\delta  \text{, } x≠5$$

It doesn't matter that $x≠5$ as in limits we don't talk about what will happen when we reach there.

As we see now our L.H.S. is in the form $|f(x)-L|$ but our R.H.S. is different. we can then equate the R.H.S. to express it in terms of $\epsilon$.

$$ 2\delta= \epsilon \Longleftrightarrow \delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2} $$

I think that the above thing does not makes sense.

for example $4<5$ and $4<6$ but $5≠6$.

So how can one say that $2\delta=\epsilon$ base on just this fact that $|f(x)-L|$ is less than both as we see 4 is less than both 5 and 6 but this does not mean that 5=6.

Comment: No the definition says that there exists a $\delta$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$, and you have proved that such $\delta$ exists and the value is $\delta=\epsilon/2$. In your analogy, the logic should be $2<3$ implies $4<6$.

Comment: There are different conventions for limits, but the most common definition has $0 < | x-c| < \delta$ rather than just $|x-c|<\delta$, and you'll need to use *that* definition if you want the limit to exist in this case. (That's what allows you to ignore what happens at $x=5$.)

Comment: @HansLundmark  Yes, it is true. I didn't mention it because I thought that the people here know the definition. I am using the standard definition only. And can you explain why it allows to ignore what happens at $x=5$.

Comment: Well, if $0<|x-5|$, then $x$ can't be $5$, can it?

Comment: @HansLundmark Oh, yes I see it. You are correct. Can I say that it is not necessary that $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ but if we want to express it in terms of epsilon we can say that.

Comment: The limit says that for any $\epsilon> 0$ that *at least one* $\delta$ exist.  In actuality an *infinite* number of $\delta$ exist.  Your job is to find *one* of them-- not the only one.  If we choose $\delta = \frac {\epsilon}2$ that will by *one* which works and that is all you need.  There is nothing that says it is the *only* one and that $\delta$ *must* be $\frac \epsilon 2$.  In fact for *any* $\delta \le \frac {\epsilon}2$ it will be fine

Comment: The proof is saying "If we *choose* to have $2\delta = \epsilon$ every thing will work".  It is *not* saying "If we want everything to work we need to have $2\delta = \epsilon$". .... If it were up to me I was write it as "If we want everything to work we need $2\delta \le \epsilon$ but *any* $\delta: 0 < \delta \le \frac {\epsilon}2$ will work"... This is like saying "If we need to find a number bigger than $4$ than $5$ will work... but its not the only one that will work.... $6$ will work too".

Comment: @fleablood Yes that seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of the proof is this:

> If $0<|x-5|<\delta$, **and** if $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, **then** $|f(x)-10| < \epsilon$.

The statement above is true for all values of $\epsilon>0$, which means $10$ is indeed the limit of $f$ as $x$ goes to $5$.

---

Everything else in the proof is just a particular method of how to get the exact values of $\delta$ and $\epsilon$.

There is no such thing in the proof as saying $4<5$ and $4<6$, therefore $5=6$. The proof is more similar to saying "I need some value $a$ that would satisfy the inequality $4<a$. I also know that the inequality $4<5$ is true, therefore, I can say that $a=5$ satisfies the inequality".

And this sort of reasoning is perfectly OK if you want to prove a statement of the type "There exists some $a$ for which the inequality $4<a$ is satisfied.

Comment: Yes, you are right but there are other values also that satisfy the inequality so why only a=5.

Comment: "so why only a=5."  **no-one** ever said that $a=5$ is the only possibility.  And **no-one** ever said that $\delta = \frac {\epsilon}2$ was the *only* possibility.  We are just saying that $a=5$ is *one* possibility and that $\delta = \frac {\epsilon}2$ is *one* possibility (actually $\delta = \frac {\epsilon}2$ is the *largest* possibility.  But that is not important. )  Any value $\delta = w$ where $0 < w \le \frac {\epsilon}2$ will do just fine.  You could have done $\delta = \frac {\epsilon}{10000000} < \frac {\epsilon}2$ if we wanted to.

Comment: @MohdSaad Where did anyone say "only $a=5$?"

Comment: @MohdSaad You are falsly applying the "only" part into the discussion, when there is no such thing in the original proof. Basically, to caricature it, you are having this talk: "Hey, can you prove that there exists some $a$ that satisfies the inequality $4<a$?" "Yes, sure, since we know $4<5$, we see that $a=5$ satistfies it." "But how do you know $a=5$? $a$ could also be $6$, right?"

Comment: @fleablood Okay , So it is not restricted. I what to know why we can say that $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ is the largest possiblity?

Comment: @5xum Yes, that word *only* makes a big difference.

Comment: @MohdSaad The fact that $\delta=\frac\epsilon2$ is the largest possibility is not really relevant to the proof. What matters is that it *is* a possibility.

Comment: @5xum Yes , Now I see the reason.

Comment: This is entirely a tangent: If $\delta > \frac{\epsilon}2$ then If we had an $x$ so that $5+\frac \epsilon 2 < x < 5 + \delta$ then we'd have $|x-5| < \delta$ but we would have $|x-5| > \frac \epsilon 2$ and $|2x -10|=|f(x) -10| > \epsilon$.  So that choice of $\delta$ fails... In doing a $\delta-\epsilon$ proof we need an argument to go from $\delta$ to $\epsilon$ but it need not be exact or "tight".  In this argument $|x-5|<\delta \iff |f(x)-10| < 2\delta$ is *very* tight and exact. But it needn't and won't always be.

Comment: The reason I know $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}2$ is the *largest* is because:  $|x-5|<\delta \iff |2x-10|=|f(x)-10|<2\delta$ is an "if **and only if**" statement so we have $|x-5|<\delta\le\frac{\epsilon}2$ we get $|f(x)-10|< 2\delta \le \epsilon$.  But if we have $\frac {\epsilon}2 < \delta$ we could have $\frac {\epsilon}2 \le |x-5|<\delta$ get a bad result.  ... but our proof only needs $|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ it does NOT need (and usually it would be impossible to have) $|x-a| < \delta \iff |f(x)-L|< \epsilon$. That's why I know it is the biggest. And that is why I don't care.